# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 at recyclerview getItemViewType when updating database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room, indexoutofboundsexception

i have an adapter with 5 viewTypes, with options to edit the list such as add, delete, check, unCheck, hide and show items. when i press delete an item (the item is deleted from room database and the list is notified through a combination of liveData and viewModel), the app crashes with this error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jakrta.solo, PID: 8708
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.jakrta.solo.ui.tasks.TasksListAdapter.getItemViewType(TasksListAdapter.java:547)
```

This occures in most times (90%), the error message always shows matched numbers in both index and size, it looks like when the item is deleted from database getItemViewType is still dealing with the old size of the array although the adapter has received the new array.

here is the code and the error message:

```
    `viewModel.observeActiveTasks()
                .observe(this, tasks -> {

                    activeTasksAdapter.submitList(tasks);

                    if(!(tasks.isEmpty()))
                        activeHeaderAdapter.submitList(true);
                    else
                        activeHeaderAdapter.clearList();

                });`
```

```
    public class TasksListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TasksListAdapter.TasksListViewHolder>
       
{

    public List<Task> tasks= new ArrayList<>();
    private int taskOrder;
    private TasksListViewHolder holder
    ItemClicked activity;

    public TasksListAdapter(ItemClicked activity, int taskOrder)
    {
        this.taskOrder= taskOrder;
        this.activity=activity;
    }
public class TasksListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener
    {


        private AppCompatTextView tvTaskName;
        private AppCompatCheckBox cbTask;
        private AppCompatRadioButton bSelect;
        private AppCompatImageButton btArrowUp;
        private AppCompatImageButton btArrowDown;
        private AppCompatImageButton bDelete;

        public TasksListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, int viewType)
        {
            super(itemView);

            tvTaskName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskName);
            cbTask=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbTask);
            bSelect=itemView.findViewById(R.id.bSelect);
            btArrowUp= itemView.findViewById(R.id.btArrowUp);
            btArrowDown= itemView.findViewById(R.id.btArrowDown);
            bDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.bDelete);


        }
    }

@NonNull
    @Override
    public TasksListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {


            switch (viewType) {

                case 1: {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_layout_one, parent, false);

                    return new TasksListViewHolder(view, viewType);
                }

                case 2: {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_layout_two, parent, false);

                    return new TasksListViewHolder(view, viewType);
                }

                case 3: {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_layout_three, parent, false);

                    return new TasksListViewHolder(view, viewType);
                }

                case 4: {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_layout_four, parent, false);

                    return new TasksListViewHolder(view, viewType);
                }

                case 5: {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_layout_five, parent, false);

                    return new TasksListViewHolder(view, viewType);
                }
            }

        return null;
    }

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TasksListViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        this.holder= holder;
        holder.tvTaskName.setText(tasks.get(position).getName());
        holder.cbTask.setChecked(tasks.get(position).getIsCompleted());

        if(position == tasks.size()-1)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_task_list);
        else
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#19212188"));
        if (tasks.get(position).isHasSubTasks()) {

            if ( position == tasks.size()-1 ||
                    tasks.get(position+1).getTaskOrder()<=tasks.get(position).getTaskOrder()) {

                holder.btArrowUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.btArrowDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {

                holder.btArrowUp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.btArrowDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            holder.btArrowUp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btArrowDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

holder.bDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.onItemDeleted(tasks, position);

            }
        });

        holder.cbTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean checked = ((AppCompatCheckBox) v).isChecked();

                    activity.onTtemChecked(position, checked);

            }
        });
}

public void submitList(final List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks.clear();
        this.tasks = tasks;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tasks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
//        return super.getItemViewType(position);

        switch (tasks.get(position).getTaskOrder()) {
            case 1:
                return 1;
            case 2:
                return 2;
            case 3:
                return 3;
            case 4:
                return 4;
            case 5:
                return 5;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

public interface ItemClicked {

        //        void onItemClicked(int index);
        void onItemDeleted(List<Task> tasks, position);
        void onMultipleItemsDeleted(List<Task> selectedTasksList);
        void onItemAdded(Task task);
        void onTtemChecked(int position, boolean isCompleted);
        void onItemMoved();
        void onTtemRestricted(Task task);
        void onLaterUpdates();
        void onHiddenItemsRestored(Task task, int position);
        void onHiddenItemsRemoved(int position);

    }
}
```

```
public class TasksFragment extends Fragment implements CalendarFragment.OnDataDelivered,
    CalendarAdapter.OnViewHolderCreated, TasksListAdapter.ItemClicked
    , BottomSheetFragment.TaskAdded, TaskCallback {





public void setTasksList () {

    taskListsRecyclerView = binding.tasksListRecyclerView;

    activeHeaderAdapter= new TasksHeaderAdapter();
    activeTasksAdapter = new TasksListAdapter(this, taskOrder);

    completedHeaderAdapter= new TasksHeaderAdapter();
    completedTasksAdapter = new TasksListAdapter(this, taskOrder);

    tasksConcatAdapter= new ConcatAdapter(activeHeaderAdapter,
            activeTasksAdapter, completedHeaderAdapter, completedTasksAdapter);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    taskListsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    taskListsRecyclerView.setAdapter(tasksConcatAdapter);
    RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    taskListsRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
    viewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);
  }@Override
public void onItemDeleted(List<Task> tasks, int position) {viewModel.deleteTaskById(tasks.get(position).getTaskId());
}
```

i tried to catch an error on getItemViewType but the app moved on and gave another error message (invoking itemView on a null pointer at createViewHolder). i didn't try to remove the deleted item manually from the array because i still has multiple delete option and this answer is not acceptable there, but at least i tried notifyDataSetChanged() after deleting the item from the database but to no avail.

Comment: `(tasks.get(position).getTaskOrder())` this line has the exception raised; you need to check the `tasks` size and make sure you don't get out of bounds index

Comment: I've already tried to use if( position >= tasks.size) but adapter just moved to creatViewHolder and gave me another exception for the same problem.

Comment: If you need to do that the use if(position > tasks.size) instead

Comment: Hej Abdulla, can you show the code for your Adapter? For example what does 'activeHeaderAdapter.submitList(true)'?

Comment: @AbdullaBashir yeah, your code from Adapter would be really helpful, especially the part where you delete item

Comment: @DanielKnauf  I edited the question to add my adapter code (i removed all ItemTouchHelper code since it is not related to simplify the code snippet, as well as related TaskFragment code, if there is anything else needed just tell me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ruslan the question has been edited, please read the above comment

Comment: @AbdullaBashir what is happening in VM when you call ```viewModel.deleteTaskById(tasks.get(position).getTaskId())```?

Comment: @AbdullaBashir error which you receive `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2` is very typical to cases when adapter is not being notified about removed items, so I hope VM code will help to understand what is going on there

Comment: @Ruslan viewModel calls repository which in turn calls TaskDao for this method  @Query("DELETE FROM Task WHERE taskId = :taskId")
    void deleteTaskById(long taskId); - no more, no less.

Comment: @AbdullaBashir got it, how you delete that corresponding item from Adapter?

Comment: @Ruslan why do i need to delete it? LiveData will fetch the changed data from my database and  pass it to submitList which will invoke notifyDataSetChanged. All my other editing list features work this way, isn't that right? .. however, i've tried before to delete the task from my list and use notifyDataSetChanged, also to delete it and pass the list again through submitList but no change.

Comment: @AbdullaBashir sorry didn't notice it initially, yeah it looks like it should take care of it. I guess that somehow this could be related to the fact that you are adding all these adapters to `ConcatAdapter`, but in theory it should also update itself. Please give a try to Daniel's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your Adapter by using [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter). It will manage updating the list and animate any changed (see also [DiffCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil.ItemCallback) for better update handling).

ListAdapter supports your approach with data changes via LiveData. When a new data set is submitted you just call `adapter.submitList(dataList)` to update the adapter.